# IDA FLAIR doesn't see sig files

Tags: ida, flirt-signatures

I've added the following sig files which were generated using flair 7.0 to ida 7.0

[image]

I want ida to find known function names from the sig files,

when I list the FLIRT signature files I don't see the sig files, why might be the problem?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to place them into a cpu specific subdirectory, e.g. `pc`.